# Auto cut text from an image

Tags: windows, gratis, pixel-graphics

A friend asked me how to ***auto*** remove the words "I Smell The Blood Of Les Tricoteuses" from this (cut only words, for use elsewhere). I have no idea (apparently, long hours with the Gimp are not acceptable, just something point & click)

[image]

Note, if you want to remove remove that text and somehow ***replace it with nearby background - in a harmonious way*** - visit https://online.theinpaint.com, which gave me this:
[image]

Is there any gratis software ***for Windows*** that would cut those words??

A bonus if it could also cut the red splodges below (blood?), leaving the "parchment" background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net/index.html), which has the function that is called the magic wand. It will select the area e.g. the red area and you can delete it. The cutting can be modified as you wish so areas where it overlaps to background not intended to be removed, can just be changed by dragging the wand. You can also zoom in and remove pixel wise.

I have made an example below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. Several paint programs have a magic wad feature, but that's the easiest part of the challenge. I have edited the question and bolded the most important requirement - "`replace it with nearby background - in a harmonious way`".